# Create a PLSQL sequence which gives random values?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My question is about PL SQL sequence which need to give random  values between start with value and max value. Can we able to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLSQL generate random integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417788/plsql-generate-random-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE`.  Here is a brief proof of concept:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  x number;
begin
  x := dbms_random.value(3, 9);
  dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
/

7.77738390408807611656323701045019115674


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You may want to take a look at the whole package: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS040

Comment: Instead of using Number.. try Pls_integer. You will get values in digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that might be useful. It's not quite random, as all it basically does is take a sequential sequence number and jumbles the digits. To avoid things like '100' and '1000' both returning the number '1' I add a random digit 1-9 to the start value.

The reason for this over a straight random number is to avoid repeats/collisions in the values return, which will happen with random functions.

You could of course go with the DBMS_RANDOM approach and build in a check against the target table.column value to check the value has not already been used.

So, here is my quick and dirty randomish solution:

I haven't thoroughly tested this.

First create a normal sequence:

`CREATE SEQUENCE the_seq START WITH 10000;`

Now the function to randomly scramble a number returned from a sequence:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_seq_val RETURN NUMBER IS
   l_seq_val   VARCHAR2(50);
   l_ret_val   VARCHAR2(50);
   l_seq_len   NUMBER;
   l_digit     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(the_seq.NEXTVAL))) INTO l_seq_val FROM dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( 'Seq: ' || l_seq_val );
   l_seq_len := LENGTH(l_seq_val);
   l_ret_val := TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1,9)); -- Avoid having 0 as leading digit below
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( ' Ret: ' || l_ret_val );
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_seq_len LOOP
      l_digit := TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1, LENGTH(l_seq_val)));
      l_ret_val := l_ret_val || SUBSTR(l_seq_val, l_digit, 1);
      l_seq_val := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_seq_val, '(?<=^.{' || l_digit || '})', '' );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( ' Dig: ' || l_digit );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( ' NowSeq: ' || l_seq_val );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( ' Ret: ' || l_ret_val );
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( ' RETURN: ' || l_ret_val );
   RETURN l_ret_val;
END;
/

show err
```

Now TEst it:

```
select rn, get_seq_val() sv from ( select rownum rn from dual connect by level < 20 );
```

My output:

```
        RN         SV
---------- ----------
         1     801410
         2     610011
         3     140441
         4     514411
         5     341400
         6     341100
         7     801404
         8     301404
         9     310014
        10     800100
        11     615005
        12     510500
        13     850155
        14     205000
        15     201000
        16     705100
        17     550050
        18     411555
        19     615000

19 rows selected.
```